# Input command for real time video streaming with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, real-time, rtp

My real time application renders an image into a byte[] every frame and I want to feed it into a RTP video stream using ffmpeg. However, the tutorials/documentations I find either refer to a [device or application](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) (-i video="Some device") or to [files](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) in the hard drive. Is it possible to send the frame data from code to a ffmpeg stream?

Comment: Yes, google for AVIOContext.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipes to transfer the frame onto ffmpeg. Just replace the `-i somefile` with `-i -` which tells ffmpeg to read from the pipe.

Comment: https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/2017/02/12/a-simple-way-to-read-and-write-audio-and-video-files-in-c-using-ffmpeg-part-2-video/ This is a great example on using pipes with C code and ffmpeg